# Deploying multiple instances of contract, no error but no deployment

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I am trying to deploy the same contract code to create multiple instance:

```
const contract = require('truffle-contract')

var Greeter3 = artifacts.require("Greeter3"); 

module.exports = function(deployer) {

  contract("Greeter3", async (accounts) => {
    it("should be initialized twice", async () => {
      let instance1 = await Greeter3.new();
      let instance2 = await Greeter3.new();
      assert.notEqual(instance1.address, instance2.address);

      deployer.deploy(instance1);
      deployer.deploy(instance2);
    });
  });

};
```

No error message is returned, but the deployment fails:

```
6_multi.js
==========

   > Saving migration to chain.
   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:                   0 ETH
```

What does this response mean?

Comment: This looks like a confused mixture of a truffle test script and a truffle migration script. You should start by fixing that, to begin with. A truffle migration script doesn't need to declare neither `contract(...)` nor `it(...)`. You might want to read [this truffle-migration tutorial](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#running-migrations) first.

Comment: The tutorial does not specify how to deploy multiple instances of the same contract. How would that be done?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but shouldn't you be `await`ing `deployer.deploy()`?

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63565/16043), of am example script which you can use, I believe, for your purpose.